# Simultainous transactions oracle

Tags: java, oracle, spring-mvc, mybatis

I'm currently using mybatis in java and oracle database, the scenario that appeared was: I go to sql developer, execute an insert, then I go to my spingmvc app do something that requieres let's say an insert to, the application will do nothing until i do commit or rollback on the query executed on sql developer, once I do that, the web application continues it workflow and do the insert to

is this normal? it's part from oracle or mybatis? thanks

Comment: @AlexPoole I didn't meant that I can't see the information, I can't perform any other operation on database until I do commit or rollback on the sql developer query

Comment: Are you inserting the same data in both sessions - or at least, the same primary/unique key value, or a column that has a unique index on it? It is normal for the second session to block in that case, as it doesn't know yet whether the insert will be allowed - that isn't resolved until the first session commits or rolls back.

Comment: @AlexPoole No, it doesn't rise any errors, it just hold the sql execution of my web app until I do a commit/rollback on the query executed on sql developer

Comment: [Read about DML locks](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_locks001.htm#SQLRF55502).

Comment: @AlexPoole that was it, thanks